# External force as defined in Landau's statistical mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

I was reading Landau's volume 5 on statistical mechanics and there in 5th Russian edition page 62 he mentions the following (translated very roughly) that 
assume we have Hamiltonian system which consists of point particles and which is described by Hamiltonian that depends on $q, p$ and also parameter $r$ which we interpret as radius vector from origin of our coordinate system to some point in space.

Then, the force on surface element $ds$ which is located ar $r$ is given by

$$ F = -\frac{\partial H(p,q,r)}{\partial r}. $$

In the previous equation, $H$ is Hamiltonian of our system of point particles.

I have trouble understanding why this definition intuitively corresponds to the force. I am not sure how to interpret this equation. I am not sure how would I experimentally verify this definition.

I would be happy if someone could explain the intuition behind this definition.

Comment: This is one of Hamiltonian equations of classical mechanics, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics

Comment: @M_kaj thanks for reply! I am not sure, as far as I know then Hamiltonian equations have derivatives with respect to q and p in them. I do not know what to do if there are external parameters.

Comment: The external parameters are potentials which must be evaluated at the position of the particle.

Comment: I would expect the Hamiltonian also to be a function of radial momentum $p_r$ that is canonically conjugate to $r$.

Comment: This is just the work-energy theorem, using "work done = force $\times$ distance" as the *definition* of a generalized force. For a closed system the Hamiltonian is the sum of the KE and PE.

Comment: @Void I would think so too, I guess, but no conjugate momentum is defined.

Comment: @alephzero Can you please be more explicit? I mean yes, we can define whatever we want, but why is this what we intuitively would call a force?